# What's the difference between "Time in App Per User" on Fabric and "Daily User Engagement" on Firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics, google-fabric

Recently I migrated from Google Analytics / Crashlytics / Fabric to Firebase. I notice on Firebase there is a metric called Daily User Engagement:

[image]

While on Fabric there is "Time in App Per User":

[image]

I was just wondering, what is the difference between these two? I also did a major update of my app when started using Firebase, so wanted to compare how the user engagement changed or stayed the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both metrics measure similar things, but slightly differently, due to different SDK's being used between Fabric and Firebase for gathering Analytics data.

For Daily User Engagement, this is based on the number of users who have your app in the foreground each day for long enough to trigger the user_engagement Analytics event, which gets triggered periodically.

The Time in App metric is a measure of how long a daily active user is active in the app on a specific day. A user can have multiple sessions in a day which would be included in the Time in App metric.

So, if a user were to look at your app for a minute each time, and use it three times times a day, then his time in app would be 3 minutes.

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask you one more question? If my Time in App Per User was about 2:30 and now my Daily User Engagement is around 5:40, is it safe for me to assume that the activity has doubled and thats it's very positive? Or is Daily User Engagement usually a much larger figure due to the way it's measured? Trying to figure out if there has been an improvement since I updated the app.

Comment: Fabric Analytics will likely count more sessions and users than Google Analytics (Firebase) because it requires the app to have less time in foreground and background before a session/active user is officially captured and counted.

So, your "Time in App" metric will likely be based on more Analytics events than "Daily User Engagement". Based on that, I can feasibly see there being a large discrepancy between the two numbers. Generally speaking, I don't think drawing comparisons between the two metrics will be very useful in your case.